# Display price suffix on WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm looking for a way to display a price suffix in the WooCommerce emails. Like: ex.VAT
Is there a short snippet to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the file found at

```
wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-order-items.php -> wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php
```

into your store’s child theme .

Note that if you customize the parent theme rather than the child theme, any changes will be overwritten with theme updates.

Change code in wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php

Before

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?>
</td>
```

After

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align:middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;">
            <?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ) ); ?> ex. VAT
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this customization without changing template files, by filtering woocommerce_order_formatted_line_subtotal
Like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_formatted_line_subtotal', 'BN_add_price_suffix_subtotal', 10, 3 );

function BN_add_price_suffix_subtotal( $subtotal ) {
    
    $suffix =' ex. VAT';
    return $subtotal . $suffix;
}
```

Add this to the functions.php file in your child theme.